# UITextView touch events not firing

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` that I want to detect a single tap for.

It looks like I would be fine with simply overriding `touchesEnded:withEvent` and checking `[[touches anyObject] tapCount] == 1` , however this event doesn't even fire.

If I override the 4 events like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan (tapCount:%d)", touch.tapCount);
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        NSLog(@"touches moved");
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded (tapCount:%d)", touch.tapCount);
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        NSLog(@"touches cancelled");
}
```

I get output like this:

```
> touchesBegan (tapCount:1)
> touchesCancelled 
> touchesBegan (tapCount:1) 
> touches moved 
> touches moved
> touches moved 
> touchesCancelled
```

It seems I never get the `touchesEnded` event.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you take out your calls to super?

Comment: I've done something similar with a UITextView subclass to detect single and double taps -- it works perfectly on 2.x devices, but not on 3.0.

Comment: @Reed I expect your text view won't scroll then.

Comment: My guess is that the new Copy/Paste functionality is interfering with the touchesEnded event.  I wonder if I can turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:  I ended up using the technique here:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/94569#94569

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but the UITextView does need to utilize the touch events to do the popup menu for copy & paste for 3.0, so that might explain why it swallows this event.

Pretty lame if you ask me.

Update:  I blogged about this here:  http://benscheirman.com/2009/07/detecting-a-tap-on-a-uitextview

Comment: your blog link has changed: http://benscheirman.com/2009/07/detecting-a-tap-on-a-uitextview

Answer (score 1):

I subclassed UITextview like so, which seems to work, even with IOS 5.0.1. The key is to override touchesBegan as well, not just touchesEnded (which is what I'm really interested in).

```
@implementation MyTextView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    return [super initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event { 
    // If not dragging, send event to next responder
    if (!self.dragging) 
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event]; 
    else
        [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event { 
    // If not dragging, send event to next responder
    if (!self.dragging) 
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
    else
        [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
    if (action == @selector(copy:))
        return NO;
    if (action == @selector(cut:))
        return NO;
    if (action == @selector(select:))
        return NO;
    if (action == @selector(selectAll:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off Cut/Copy/Paste by overriding the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method, so you could just return NO for all the actions you don't want to permit.

See the [UIResponder documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder%5FClass/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canPerformAction:withSender:)...

Hopefully that will stop your touches from being eaten.

Comment: I tried overriding this method and ran into crashes.  I returned NO for @selector(select:) and @selector(selectAll:) but it still allowed the selecting.

Comment: Ok, fixed the crashes (I had forgotten to pass the rest over to super)  anyway, it seems to have no effect.  I can still copy text.

Comment: The documentation says that this method will also be called further up the responder chain, so it's possible you'll also need to override it in the containing views...