# iPhone touch cancelling in OS 3.0

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a new iPhone app that has the following (and only the following) `UIView` heirarchy:

```
UIWindow -> UIScrollView -> UIViewSubclass
```

The `UIScrollView` is the `view` of a `UIViewController`. In `UIViewSubclass` I want to be tracking and responding to touch events and have set up the "standard four" handling routines therein. Under the Simulator running the 2.2.1 OS everything works as expected. However under the Simulator running under the 3.0 OS I'm getting the same ["event eating" exhibited by the new `UITextView` behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096069/uitextview-touch-events-not-firing). As said before though I don't have a `UITextView` anywhere in my app.

What's eating my touch events, and how do I keep it from doing so? I've heard I need to override `canPerformAction:withSender:` in every view in my hierarchy; say it isn't so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the same problem, but try setting the UIScrollView’s “canCancelContentTouches” property to NO.

http://www.alexc.me/uiscrollview-and-uidatepicker/153/